# Discussing implementation of list flattener function in scala

Tags: list, scala, recursion, functional-programming

The flatten function is a function which take a list of list and return a list which is the concatenation of all the lists. As an exercise for [functional programming in scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala), we have to implement that function with a linear complexity. My solution is :

```
def flatten[A](l: List[List[A]]): List[A] = {
    def outer(ll: List[List[A]]):List[A]  = {
        ll match {
            case Nil => Nil
            case Cons(h,t) => inner(t, h)
        }
    }
    def inner(atEnd: List[List[A]], ll: List[A]): List[A] = {
        ll match {
            case Nil => outer(atEnd)
            case Cons(h,t) => Cons(h, inner(atEnd, t))
        }
    }
    outer(l)
}
```

It works. Now I looked at the [solution proposed](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answerkey/datastructures/15.answer.scala) :

```
def append[A](a1: List[A], a2: List[A]): List[A] =
    a1 match {
        case Nil => a2
        case Cons(h,t) => Cons(h, append(t, a2))
    }

def flatten2[A](l: List[List[A]]): List[A] =
    foldRight(l, Nil:List[A])(append)
```

I am suspicious that `flatten2` is really linear. At each iteration of `foldLeft`, the function `append` is called. This function will parse all the nodes of the accumulator.  The first time, the accumulator is `Nil`, the second it is `l.get(1)` then `l.get(1) + l.get(2)`... So the first list in `l` won't be crossed only once, but `l.length - 1` until the end of the function. Am I right ?

While my implementation really cross each list only once. Is my implementation really faster ?

Comment: In case this `List` is the immutable scala `List`, it have to be linear (except for the last part), because `List` cannot be reused. Yours is also linear, you add values (`h`) one-by-one.

Comment: I don't know why it (if by `it` you mean the `flatten2` implementation) have to be linear. It is true that list are immutable, but we can create as many of them as we want. I suspect `flatten2` to recreate a new list, which is the concatenation of the accumulator and the value of the new list, at each iteration of `foldRight`.

Comment: Just add some pritln statements, and run it in repl

Comment: @Moebius, yes, I meant `flatten2`, that is also linear. It is because of this line: `case Nil => a2`, it does not have to recreate the tail of the list, it just reuses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider for example `flatten2 (List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5), List(6)))`, which expands to:

```
append(List(1,2,3),
       append(List(4,5),
              append(List(6),
                     Nil)))
```

As [a comment in the link](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answerkey/datastructures/15.answer.scala) says, "`append` takes time proportional to its first argument" and therefore "this function is linear in the total length of all lists".  (On the other hand, neither `flatten2` nor `flatten` is tail-recursive, though.)